# Chart.js - change which data the legend uses for the coloured box

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart that always shows 4 bars.  The bars are coloured dynamically. It looks like the coloured box takes its colour from the first data.  I would like to use the colour from the 4th (last) data value. Maybe the `options:plugins:legend:label:sort` function helps but I don't understand what it does.

**options**

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0)'
      }
    },
    y: {
      display: false,
      min: 0,
      max: 4
    },
  },
  plugins: {
     legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
     }
   }
}
```

So I don't know if I can change the data that the box color comes from, or if there is a config option somewhere where I can change it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `generateLabels` function as described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration).

Please take a look at below runnable sample code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [300, 50, 100],
      backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: chart => {
            let ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
            let color = ds.backgroundColor[ds.backgroundColor.length - 1];
            return [{
              datasetIndex: 0,
              text: ds.label,
              fillStyle: color,
              strokeStyle: color
            }];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="180"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up with [@uminder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887870/11542205), if you want to keep the hide/show chart and the line-through style after clicking on the legend, you can add the following line:

```
options: {
  responsive: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        generateLabels: chart => {
          let ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
          let color = ds.backgroundColor[ds.backgroundColor.length - 1];
          return [{
            datasetIndex: 0,
            text: ds.label,
            fillStyle: color,
            strokeStyle: color,
+           hidden: !chart.isDatasetVisible(0)
          }];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```